# Laravel - Localization in api request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Recently, I have upgraded from `Laravel 5.3` to `Laravel 5.2`.

In this, I have defined two separate `route` files for `web` and `api` respectively in the routes directory.

I do have a `multilingual` portal. I am providing option to change the language. For that, I am using `localization` middleware. Please see my code below:

**Localization.php:**

```
class Localization {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard=null){
        if(!Auth::guard($guard)->guest()){
            if (Session::has('current_locale')) {
                $locale = Session::get('current_locale');
            } 
            else {
                $locale = Auth::guard($guard)->user()->getLocale();
                Session::set('current_locale', $locale);
            }
            App::setLocale($locale);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The **routes/web.php** is as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['localization:web']], function () {
        //Some web routes here
    });
});
```

And **routes/api.php** is as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/service/v1', 'middleware' => ['api']], function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','localization:api']], function() {
        //Some api routes here
    });
});
```

**config/auth.php** is as:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ]
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ]
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]
    ]
];
```

On choosing different language, I am storing the selected language in a `session` and I use it across the subsequent requests to set the App language.

But, the problem is, I am using `Ajax` requests to get the data using `APIs`. And in which the guard `api` is set in `localization` middleware, hence I am not able to access the `Session` that's why I am not able to get the multi-lingual data from database.

Any solution? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue my self by updating `$middleware` array in `app/Http/Kernal.php` as:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,  
    'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',
];
```

Hope this might help someone.